# How do I get the XCode Project URL programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm curious if there is a way to programmatically get the location of the .xcodeproj package within an Objective-C (or Swift) class contained within that package. I'd like to make a simple utility that puts files directly into the containing folder based on various app events, but I would rather avoid hard coding the path.

Essentially I want to create a target (and a reusable class) that builds swift files for NSManagedObject subclasses based on the Core Data model present in the app.

Comment: There is no `.xcodeproj` within a running app. Please clarify.

Comment: Are you on Mac OS or iOS?

Comment: I merely want the app to know where the .xcodeproj file is that created it... I found that passing the ${PROJECT_DIR} environment variable through the plist file was the easiest way of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 3):

I found out the trick here is to add an item to your plist file that contains value ${PROJECT_DIR}, then you can get the location in your code with

```
var projectPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary.objectForKey("com.myapp.project_dir") as String
```

This assumes the plist key is "com.myapp.project_dir", of course.